# Maximizing Render Field of View in Interior Scene

Tags: camera

I'm new to Blender and love most things about it, but the camera is hard to work with, especially in tightly enclosed interior settings.

When I've positioned the camera where I want it and bring up the camera view (Ctrl + Alt + 0), it only captures a small portion (maybe 50 percent) of what's in the viewport. When I try resizing the window, it doesn't go all the way to the edges, so the only way to get everything in the shot is to zoom out... but that's often not an option with an interior scene, because I end up going through a wall. Changing the focal length distorts the image.

Are there any other options to solve this problem? In most other 3d apps I've used, you can simply resize the render window to fit what you're seeing, and even go beyond the field of view. Is there anything like this in Blender? Are there some camera constraints I can turn off for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sensor size in the camera settings. Or you can change the focal length. But what about distortion for a wide lens - it's physics, you cannot cheat it. If you want, you can use orthographic, or panoramic camera (the latter seems to work in cycles only). If you want an impossible camera shot, you also can make some of your walls to be transparent for camera rays from outside, and make the shot through the wall with the lens focal length you want.

Comment: Those are useful workarounds, but not really what I was looking for. It's not an "impossible shot," as Blender clearly is capable of capturing that part of the image (if I hit Shift + Z, there it is). So the programmers have decided to artificially limit what I can do with the camera, I assume because they want it to match the limitations of a real world camera for some pedantic reason. So I was hoping there's some way to disable those restrictions, or perhaps someone familiar with Blender's coding can point me to where I need to go to hack the source code.

Comment: I think you really didn't try to play with Sensor size in the camera settings. Just go to camera view (numpad 0), and increase the sensor size until the view will satisfy you. Just think about the fact, that the viewport of the 3d view also mimics a lens (default is 35mm), and a sensor. So if you have the same lens in the camera, you can have the same view from the camera as from the 3d view. The only thing to change is the sensor size.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It's a slightly different method than what I'm used to, but it seems to be effectively the same thing!

Comment: new software - new buttons, but for centuries the idea is the same :-)